# Change Anaconnda Install Directory Ubuntu

Tags: installation, directory, anaconda3

I moved anaconda installation from one directory (/lunarc/nobackup/projects/snic2021-6-102/sattars/codes/anaconda3) to another (/lunarc/nobackup/projects/lu2023-12-3/sattars/codes/anaconda3).

I updated also .bashrc file with following:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/lunarc/nobackup/projects/lu2023-12-3/sattars/codes/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/lunarc/nobackup/projects/lu2023-12-3/sattars/codes/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/lunarc/nobackup/projects/lu2023-12-3/sattars/codes/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/lunarc/nobackup/projects/lu2023-12-3/sattars/codes/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

However, the base directory is still pointing to old location and thus not working.
How can I change active env location and others to make conda work at new directory?
[image]

I am expecting anaconda to work at new location.